# Depending on faliure to prove in prolog

Tags: prolog

Consider this code

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
p(1).
p(3).
p(5).
p(7).

predecessor(A, B) :- A #= B - 1. % is true for pairs 

q(X) :- predecessor(P, X), \+ p(P).
```

If I query `?- p(X)` I correctly get the results

> ?- p(X).
>   X = 1 ;
>   X = 3 ;
>   X = 5 ;
>   X = 7.

But if I query `?- q(X)` then I get `false`.
I realize that `\+` is really not negation but faliure to prove, but what if not being able to prove something is sufficient for another predicate being true?

I wanted to give a reasonable use case / example which is why I resorted to using clpfd. Even without using it, I have another example which I can present:

```
likes(betty, butter).
likes(betty, jam) :- fail.

dislikes(betty, Item) :- \+ likes(betty, Item).
```

This example too, has a shortcoming that `likes(betty, jam) :- fail.` isn't really doing anything. But I hope I'm able to get my point across.

Is there a way in prolog to define this dependence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specifically define the "negative universe" of possibilities if you want Prolog to provide solutions in that space.

For instance, `\+ p(X)` cannot tell you specific values of `X` because the possible `X` that meet this criteria have not been defined. You're asking Prolog to invent what `X` might possibly be, which it cannot do.

You could define the universe of all possible values, then you can define what `\+ p(X)` means:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

p(1).
p(3).
p(5).
p(7).

predecessor(A, B) :- A #= B - 1. % is true for pairs 

q(X) :- predecessor(P, X), P in 0..9, label([P]), \+ p(P).
```

Then you get:

```
2 ?- q(X).
X = 1 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 5 ;
X = 7 ;
X = 9 ;
X = 10.

3 ?-
```

Here we've told Prolog that the possible universe of `P` to choose from is defined by `P in 0..9`. Then the call `\+ p(P)` can yield specific results. Unfortunately, using `\+`, you still have to apply `label([P])` before testing `\+ p(P)`, but you get the idea.

In your other example of `likes`, it's the same issue. You defined:

```
likes(betty, butter).
likes(betty, jam) :- fail.
```

As you indicated, you wouldn't normally include `likes(betty, jam) :- fail.` since failure would already occur due to lack of a successful fact or predicate. But your inclusion is really an initial attempt to define the universe of possible choices. Without that definition, Prolog cannot "invent" what to pick from to test for a dislike. So a more complete solution would be:

```
person(jim).
person(sally).
person(betty).
person(joe).

food(jam).
food(butter).
food(eggs).
food(bread).

likes(betty, butter).
```

Then you can write:

```
dislikes(Person, Food) :-
    person(Person),
    food(Food),
    \+ likes(Person, Food).
```

Comment: This is excellent! You've solved for me what I'd been stuck on for the past couple of hours. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have a question about what `label` is doing in this. I guess it's trying to enumerate the whole range provided by the `in`, but does it enumerate it even when an input to `q` is provided? i.e. would it still go through `1..9` if `q(500)` is called? If yes, then is there any way to selectively enumerate only when `q(X)` i.e. the input to q is queried but not unnecessarily when `q(<number>)` is called?

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha `label/1` is described in the [SWI Prolog documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=labeling/2). It actually does enumerate the values. If `X` is instantiated already, then `label(X)` will not try other values for `X`.